# Index rebuild on a partitioned table taking long time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I have a table with 300M records. This table is partitioned on a week column. All the indexes on that table are partitioned and having a clustered columnstore index along with 5 non clustered indexes.

Every time we do an index rebuild, it's taking 6 hours and more, but not completing any one index at least and we will need to kill at the end. We don’t have any load in server at that point of time.

We use `dbcc reindex` with fillfactor of 80.

Please help how to debug further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reorg or rebuild?  Can you just do the NCIs?

Comment: There's a lot that could cause this. How big are the indexes? How much CPU and Memory? What other processes are running at this time? Why are you using fillfactor 80 (and bloating your index and causing more page spits, etc)? Are you rebuilding all indexes regardless of their fragmentation levels? MAXDOP setting?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using and are you reindexing all indexes or just the fragmented ones?

Comment: Are the partitions physically separated onto different physical disks, or are they simply logically separated, perhaps onto different logical volumes on the same physical disk.  If you are processing all of the index rebuilds in parallel, but they are all on the same physical disk, the disk utilization would likely cause massive slowdowns in all index rebuilds.

Comment: @user1443098 yes it’s rebuild only. I got the issue while performing on NCI only

Comment: @scsimon index are also big one like the table. Couple of them having two columns , another having four columns and another one having one column. Finally a clustered columnstore. Coming to filfactor , 80 isn’t ideal one as we do deletes and updates on that table ?? Then reg rebuild , yes. I’m doing this rebuild after checking fragmentation level which is more than 30%  . Maxdop is 4.

Comment: @cloudsafe we are using MS SQL 2016 enterprise version.

Comment: @Sudheerkrishna In that case, you can rebuild the indexes with the ONLINE option so that it does not affect live systems.

Comment: @cloudsafe the time it takes dbcc dbreindex and during alter index rebuild with online vary in time ??

Answer (score 0):

If the older date partitions are pretty static , you might benefit from partition level index rebuild / reorganize, depending on sql server version.

[Link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/70103/) To find index fragmentation at partition level

Ideally , microsoft suggests that reorganize should be used for index fragmentation between 5 and 30 % and rebuild for > 30%